# Synchronize users between XMPP and django

Tags: ios, django, xmpp, user-profile

I'm creating an iOS app which uses django as my backend. I need to have a chat functionality between users.

I heard that XMPP is good for real time communication, and I have successfully set up ejabberd as the XMPP server. But still I'm having hard time to deal with the details:
I created the app first and then the chat feature, so before I setup ejabberd, there are already users in my django DB. I need ejabberd to authenticate users against my existing DB and I have almost solved this by using external authentication. There is only one small problem, as ejabberd seems to require the jabber ID like *username@abc.com*, and here *abc* means the virtual host of ejabberd. I don't know maybe I could only use one virtual host on my server(which is the domain name)? But then at the beginning I asked the user to register using emails which are from different domains of course, e.g. gmail.com, yahoo.com, but *username@gmail.com@abc.com* is not a valid jabber ID, so maybe one small trick I can do here is to convert first @ to # and handle it properly in the python script in the backend. But maybe I did it totally wrong?

Another issue is about user profile. I stored the user information as well in my django DB, e.g. display name, avatar url, etc. I learnt that I could use the vCard module if I want to get those information from XMPP server. So maybe I need to have duplicated information in two places? And still I haven't figured out how to synchronize the user information from DB to ejabberd. Or maybe I just need to have only one source, which is my DB, and the iOS client could then query the information from the backend whenever needed?

I feel that XMPP is not easy to setup, is it really popular to use it in your Apps? Especially if chatting is not the main functionality of your App and you are not expecting to have huge messages from big number of users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wrote:

> but username@gmail.com@abc.com is not a valid jabber ID

You are supposed to escape the user id (i.e "username@gmail").

[XEP 106](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0106.html#escaping) explains how you should escape the node part of a JID.

In python, it would look something like this:

```
def escape_node(node):
    """ """
    node.strip()
    node = node.replace('\\', "\\5c")
    node = node.replace(' ',  "\\20")
    node = node.replace('\"', "\\22")
    node = node.replace('\&', "\\26")
    node = node.replace('\'', "\\27")
    node = node.replace('\/', "\\2f")
    node = node.replace(':',  "\\3a")
    node = node.replace('<',  "\\3c")
    node = node.replace('>',  "\\3e")
    node = node.replace('@',  "\\40")
    return node
```

With regards to storing your users' details in Django. When you register your Django users in XMPP, just make sure that you also register valid vCards for them.

When a Django user changes his details, update the vCard as well.

Comment: thanks it's very helpful. it seems i need to store only the photo url instead of the actual data in vCard as it's more space efficient and the iOS client does not have to download it again(as the avatar is used somewhere else, but the XMPPFramework extensions don't support this yet ). could you maybe point me to some links which describe how to "update vCard(ejabberd specifically) from django using python", is there any tutorial of how to write python code to communicate with ejabberd in general(i assume using ejabberdctl is not the proper way)?

Comment: I use Twisted and Wokkel to communicate with the XMPP server from Python. http://wokkel.ik.nu. You can use those libraries to create an IQ stanza with a vCard as well.

Comment: I was able to sync name and photos through twisted and wokkel, but i could do it only in a standalone application. when i put it together with django, it seems reactor.run() would block, running it in a separated thread didn't help as reactor.run() would only run in main thread... and if I stop the reactor and run it again when needed then I got ReactorNotRestartable error... could you give more detailed information about how i can do this? thanks.